How do I determine the dimensions of a subvector space within $C^3$
I came across a linear algebra problem regarding vector spaces, subspaces, basis, dimensions etc. The problem goes like this:
Determine the dimensions of subvector spaces within $\mathbb C^3$:
(As an example I will leave one subspace that is what I call "general case".
$\{(x,y,z)\epsilon \mathbb C^3| z=x+iy\}$
So as I understood, dimension of vector space is number of basis vectors. What I did is first I tried to write out system of equations to check for linear independency of vectors inside the subspace, but I'm not sure it tells me anything. Also I am wondering if it was possible to simply say that since $z=x+iy$ , it is dependent on the other two vectors, and I can already assume that this subspace has dimension $<dim(\mathbb C^3)$?
If so, how exactly can I determine the dimension of this subspace, or a subspace in general. I am interested in different ways of doing this, but for now I'm trying to stick to the way without matrixes and with definitions.

Is $C=\mathbb C$ the complex numbers?

Yes, sorry, writing mistake.

Start with, say, $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}.$ What must subspaces look like? Generalize to $\mathbb{C}^3$ as a space over $\mathbb{C}$.

The rank-nullity theorem is useful for calculating the dimension of finite vector spaces. There is nothing special about $\mathbb{C}$ in this problem. All that matters is that it's a field.

You can determine the dimension of the subspace by finding the minimal number of spanning vectors. For the example you've given, $\{(0, 1, i), (1, 0, 1)\}$ is a minimally spanning set. Hence, the dimension is 2.
Another approach is to find a maximally independent set within the subspace. In this case, are there any other vectors that you can add to the above set, without making the set linearly dependent?

Hey, thanks for the contribution. Maybe a bit of a stupid question, but how do you determine the minimal number of spanning vectors? I mean how do you know how the minimal spanning set looks like?

In this case, it's simple. You know that $z$ is dependent on $x$ and $y$ so let's ignore it for now. It looks as though $x$ and $y$ are independent of each other. So let's consider the set ${(0, 1), (1, 0)}$. This spans all possible values of $x$ and $y$ (remember that you can scale by any complex number too).
From there, since you know $z$ is dependent on $x$ and $y$, you can calculate its value for the above vectors and get ${(0, 1, i), (1, 0, 1)}$.

In more complex scenarios, this approach might be harder to perform (which is where thinking of the dimension of subspaces through matrices might help). If you want to prove a set is minimally spanning, then consider some arbitrary $(x,y,z)$ in the subspace. Try proving that you can express $(x,y,z)$ as a linear combination of the basis.
